# Getting compilation errors with this function

Tags: oracle

I am getting the following error:
Warning: compiled but with compilation errors

when I try to create the following function:

```
Create or  replace function Time_Gap (v_date1, v_date2,  return varchar2 )
is   

difrence_In_Hours varchar2;
difrence_In_minutes varchar2;
difrence_In_seconds varchar2;

begin


      difrence_In_Hours := floor(((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60)/3600);
    difrence_In_minutes := floor((((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60) -
           floor(((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60);
    difrence_In_seconds :=  round((((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60) -
           floor(((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600 -
           (floor((((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60) -
           floor(((v_date2-v_date1)*24*60*60)/3600)*3600)/60)*60) ));


    return   difrence_In_Hours   || '' HRS '' ||  difrence_In_minutes   || '' MINS '' ||    difrence_In_seconds
          || '' SECS '';


end ;
/
```

what am I doing wrong???

Thanks,

Comment: Well you haven't declared the arguments or return type properly; please see the manual to see the correct syntax. It's generally helpful to tell us which error(s) you are getting though. You can see the details with `show errors` immediately after compilation, or by querying `user_errors`. There maybe other problems which those messages will help you find and understand.

Answer (score 1):

a few syntax errors,  return type should be outside of input parameters and define type of input:

```
create or replace function time_gap (v_date1 in date, v_date2 in date)
    return varchar2 is
    difrence_in_hours     varchar2(500);
    difrence_in_minutes   varchar2(500);
    difrence_in_seconds   varchar2(500);
begin
    difrence_in_hours := floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600);
    difrence_in_minutes :=
        floor ( ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) - floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600) * 3600) / 60);
    difrence_in_seconds :=
        round (
            (  ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60)
             - floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600) * 3600
             - (  floor (
                        ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) - floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600) * 3600)
                      / 60)
                * 60)));

    return difrence_in_hours || ' HRS ' || difrence_in_minutes || ' MINS ' || difrence_in_seconds || ' SECS';
end;
/
```

EDIT:

You have to give us more of the error message.  It's not saying anything.  This works fine for me:

```
declare
    function time_gap (v_date1 in date, v_date2 in date)
        return varchar2 is
        difrence_in_hours     number;
        difrence_in_minutes   number;
        difrence_in_seconds   number;
    begin
        difrence_in_hours := floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600);
        difrence_in_minutes :=
            floor ( ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) - floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600) * 3600) / 60);
        difrence_in_seconds :=
            round (
                (  ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60)
                 - floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600) * 3600
                 - (  floor (
                            (  ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60)
                             - floor ( ( (v_date2 - v_date1) * 24 * 60 * 60) / 3600) * 3600)
                          / 60)
                    * 60)));
        return trim (to_char (difrence_in_hours)) || ' HRS ' || trim (to_char (difrence_in_minutes)) || ' MINS ' || trim (
               to_char                                                                                                  (
               difrence_in_seconds)) || ' SECS';
    end;
begin
    dbms_output.put_line (time_gap (sysdate, sysdate - 2));
end;
==>
PL/SQL block executed
-48 HRS 0 MINS 0 SECS
```

Comment: The `difrence_in_hours` etc. need a size for the `varchar2` declaration too. Though they should really be numbers not strings, arguably.

Comment: Current estimates for the age of the universe are at about `4.5 * 10^17 seconds`. That's 18 characters. I don't think he's going to need 500 characters for hours.

Comment: Actually I just fixed the syntax. Wasn't really checking the arithmetic. The function is wrong, probably wont work.   The variables need to be number and cast to_char() in the output.

Comment: I made the following changes but still get the same error!Create or  replace function Time_Gap (v_date1 in date, v_date2 in date)  
return varchar2 is   

difrence_In_Hours number;
difrence_In_minutes number;
difrence_In_seconds number;

Answer (score 0):

Have you created it without checking the syntax? Always check the syntax before doing stuff like that.

As per https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B12037_01/server.101/b10759/create_function.gif just in the first line:

- you lack one of [IN][OUT][IN OUT] at every argument
- you lack datatypes for every argument
- return statement should be outside the parentheses.

At that point I stopped reading.